# Renamed file, now SVN not allowing me to commit?

Tags: svn, commit

I'm developing a ColdFusion website using Aptana. We're using SVN for version control.

I renamed a few files and am now trying to commit one of them, but I'm getting the following error:

```
'SVN Commit' has encountered a problem.
org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Illegal target for the requested operation
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Cannot commit 'R:\myPath\My-New-File-Name.cfm' because it was moved from 'R:\myPath\My-Old-File-Name.cfm' which is not part of the commit; both sides of the move must be committed together
```

This seems to indicate that I need to commit both the previous file (that was renamed) and the new renamed file together. How can I commit a file that no longer exists...?

Comment: Similar problem if you rename a directory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29563635/renamed-directory-now-svn-not-allowing-me-to-commit/

Comment: Windows is case insensitive, if you rename your file changing only case, you will get this error, so rename your file to another name (e.g file2), commit, then rename to the name you really want and commit again.

Comment: @Loenix: TortoiseSVN should handle this special case in the meanwhile so using two renames is not necessary on Windows anymore.

Comment: Wow it (SVN) couldn't be more simple, really. Working with the Tortoise context menu "rename, delete, etc." instantly works.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Commit the directory, not the file.

Think of a directory as a text file containing the list of files it contains, then you can see that to commit successfully, you need to update the directory itself so it can remove the old entry and add the new entry. This will show up in SVN as deleting the old and adding the new file (ie 2 changes to the directory, not 1 change to the file)

If only want to commit the 1 file, you will need to add the other changed files to an ignore list temporarily.

Comment: I thought of doing this but I only wanted to commit 1 file of many in the directory. But I now realized that if I select commit on the whole folder, I can uncheck all the other files and just leave the original file and the renamed file... Thank you!

Comment: Perfect, that was easier than I thought it would be!

Comment: A related problem was solved by 1) committing the folder alone 2) revert the file which had status >added< 3) (update) 4) rename file in tortoise 5) commit successful.

Comment: This answer is not correct. If you are working with svn itself (ie, command-line svn), rkiko's answer below is correct. That is: you list the old file name in your commit. This allows you to precisely commit only the renames you want, when you don't want to commit all the changes in the directory. Besides which, you are NOT committing a change to the directory as if it is a list of text files!

Answer (score 15):

Add a file with old name and do commit, Then delete the file again do commit.

Comment: This is totally the way

Answer (score 12):

Various clients seem to handle this better than others..

AnkhSVN for Visual Studio encounters this error and can't deal with it.

TortiseSVN (shell extension) works though - it knows to delete the old file and add the new one.

So if you're on Windows an easy way to work around this is to use TortiseSVN from Explorer to do a commit on the directory (which deletes the old file name and adds the new one).

Comment: Is there no sensible round this even now? It seems utterly crazy to have this issue in 2016 :(

Comment: I'm still getting stuck on this! GRR why oh why is it so awful in Visual Studio? it's actually going to be worth going onto Git I think, I cannot get a good solution and it's wasting hours of time.

Comment: was worth it before you encountered this issue :)

Answer (score 6):

In eclipse with subversion, I was able to work around this confusing error by doing a Team->synchronize at a high enough level folder in the project that it encompassed both the old and new file names and locations.  If you moved and renamed your files or if you can't figure out what precisely is going on, it can't hurt to synchronize at the very top level of your project.

When I did this, the old versions of the renamed files showed up in the synchronize view.  Once I used "override and commit" on them, they disappeared again.   At this point, the new ones will finally commit properly.

Comment: I tried simply to click the "Synchronize" button in the Synchronize view, but it did not worked. This trick works, thank you.

Comment: So, step by step, what am I supposed to do? Right click on the project and "Synchronize with Repository"? What next?

Answer (score 3):

svn commit 'R:\myPath\My-New-File-Name.cfm' 'R:\myPath\My-Old-File-Name.cfm' -m "message"

works for me. You just also need to include the deleted file.

Comment: This is the correct answer, when working with raw command-line SVN, and you don't want to commit the whole directory.

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio 2015, I tripped over a fix for Ankh SVN. In my case the error resulted from renaming a "Form1.cs" during development (and perhaps moving it). That caused issues with the old and new .resx files.

- Highlight the project in the Solution Explorer to open the pending changes view window,
- Choose File > Subversion > Pending changes
- Uncheck the Path
- Check the two or more files that subversion needs. If "new" one isn't in the list change its contents in a non-desturctive way so it will appear in the list.
- Run commit.

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a chance that one of the files is renamed.

Look at the file names in the error and see if this matches with your files.

If the file names don't match, rename your file to the one in the error and commit all the files you wanted to commit.
After this you can rename your file and commit again.

Comment: The entire question is about renaming files.

Comment: O, I see. I made a mistake. The rest of the answer could still be valid.

Answer (score 0):

If things really get messed up, the simplest solution is to delete the folder from the repository and then add it back in its current form.

SVN Wipe and Replace:

1. Copy the folder containing all of your changes to a temporary location.
2. Use SVN Delete on the folder and then commit.
3. Copy the backup copy back to your working copy and commit.

Comment: This will cut off your history for every file in that directory. I don't think you want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IntelliJ IDEA and make commit with TortoiseSVN, sometimes, it happens that the folder is not deleted by IDEA and Subversion make this error.

In that case, that means **"please, don't commit a folder/file you marked as deleted"**

Answer (score 0):

sudo svn rm offendingfile --force

sudo svn commit -m ''

Done

Answer (score 0):

For me, many of the other solutions were not working.

What finally did the trick was this:

1. I made a manual backup copy of everything in my repository folder
   except for the `.svn` folder
2. ...then reverted the repository folder
3. ...then deleted everything except the `.svn` folder in the repository folder
4. ...then copied the contents of the backup folder back into the repository folder
5. ...then committed that.

Then, and only then, did the commit finally work for me.

Answer (score -2):

TortiseSVN 
open the file in windows explorer.
select the file,right click,use **TortiseSVN**->**unversion and add to ignore list**

then the file will get rid of the SVN，becomes normal file.
thus you can do the operation to add the file to SVN,and submit it.

i use the solution solve to the issue.

Comment: This will cut off the history of the file. Much better to use `svn rename` and commit the parent folder.