# SVN: Committed together?

Tags: svn

I'm getting a prolem like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21572877/renamed-file-now-svn-not-allowing-me-to-commit), only svn is showing the error message on a new file that I merely moved from one directory to another. I don't really understand how the answer can be used in my situation. I.e., how do I do the same thing as has been suggested in [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21572877/renamed-file-now-svn-not-allowing-me-to-commit) if I have moved one new file from one directory to another. The source and destination directories are not new.

Comment: What do you mean by moving a "new file"? Is this the first commit that contains this file anywhere?

Comment: The file was renamed and then it was moved - the renaming and movement are both in this WC.

Comment: Then your working copy will have the file recorded as a single move, from a name in one directory to a name in a different directory. The answer you link applies exactly the same in your case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Renamed file, now SVN not allowing me to commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21572877/renamed-file-now-svn-not-allowing-me-to-commit)

Answer (score 0):

Diff, patch, and massage; the panacea to any subversion problem.